# UIButton shadow and rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, layer

Apologies for a simple question, I am new to swing/iOS coding.

I am trying to make a button with some shadow and rounded corners.

The problem is that I need `clipToBounds` (or similar layer property `masksToBounds`) set to `false` for the former and `true` for the latter.

I saw similar questions, but did not find any reasonable answers.

Can someone please explain how to have both shadow and rounded corners.

Thank you.